# CSS :after, content: having two values?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I've got CSS on my links depending what type of link it is. In this case it's password protected, and external link.

So I've got CSS like this:

```
a.external-link:after { padding-left: 2px; content: url(../images/icon-external-link.gif); }
a.restricted-link:after { padding-left: 2px; content: url(../images/icon-lock.png);}
```

However when I try something like this:

```
<a class="external-link restricted-link" href="some link">Some Link</a>
```

It only displays the last icon, in this case the icon-lock.png. Which makes sense, since the content value can only be set once not combined, so the last class declaration is overwriting it. Is there anyway to combine these two so I can mix and match these link classes easily (I've got 4 total). I don't want to make separate classes/images for each combo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hate to break it to you, but you're going to have to make separate classes/images for each combo. Especially as there would be no way of knowing which content should go first.

```
a.external-link.restricted-link:after
{
  content: url(ext) url(res);
}
```

vs

```
a.external-link.restricted-link:after
{
  content: url(res) url(ext);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not as bad as I thought though, I didn't realize you could do both URLs together in one content attribute. At least I don't have to do separate images for each combo.